# Jooq: Select count group by

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to count the different possibilities of the gp_status field in my table. I have an sql query that works, just cant quite figure out how to transcribe it to Jooq.

```sql
select i.gp_status, COUNT(i.gp_status) 
from ideas_service.idea i 
group by i.gp_status
```

So far in JOOQ i have this

```java
var result = dsl.select(IDEA.GP_STATUS,count(),count(IDEA.GP_STATUS))
                .from(IDEA)
                .groupBy(IDEA.GP_STATUS)
                .fetch();
```

It looks like the fields comeback correctly, but i cant figure out how to extract them.
I do know what the possible gp_status could be.

So i need to somehow get the row `where gp_status = x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you only need a single row

If you only need a single row, then you should add that predicate to your query, i.e.

```java
var result = dsl.select(IDEA.GP_STATUS, count())
                .from(IDEA)
                .where(IDEA.GP_STATUS.eq("x"))
                .groupBy(IDEA.GP_STATUS)
                .fetchOne();
```

At which point you don't really need the `GROUP BY` clause anymore:

```java
var result = dsl.select(count())
                .from(IDEA)
                .where(IDEA.GP_STATUS.eq("x"))
                .fetchOne();
```

Note that in both cases, I've used [`ResultQuery.fetchOne()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOne()), which produces a `Record`, from which you can extract the value in many ways, e.g.

```java
// Repeat the column expression from the SELECT clause
int count1 = result.get(count());

// Access columns by index, and redundantly supply the type again
// Assuming the second query was executed
int count2 = result.get(0, int.class);
```

There are many more ways.

#### If you need the entire result

If you need the entire result set, but for a specific case, just want to extract one row, then you could iterate the [`Result`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Result.html), which extends `List`, or use `Result.intoGroups(IDEA.GP_STATUS).get("x")` or any other method on `Result` to do something similar.